# .hide() function works in Chrome & Safari but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, hide, indexhibit

Hey all; I have a bit of code which is hiding one element of this website as soon as it loads. It seems to work okay in Chrome & Safari but it doesn't work in Firefox…

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%baseurl%><%basename%>/site/js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%baseurl%><%basename%>/site/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%baseurl%><%basename%>/site/js/cookie.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
path = '<%baseurl%>/files/gimgs/';

$(document).ready(function()
{
// Hide all menu options after first
$("#menu ul li.section-title").nextAll().hide();

// Show after click

$("#menu ul").each(function(){
$(this).find("li.active").prevAll().nextAll().show();
});

// Toggle Function

$("#menu ul li.section-title").click(function(){
$(this).nextAll().slideToggle("fast");
});
setTimeout('move_up()', 1);
});
</script>
```

This is running on indexhibit and can be seen here: http://www.problemwithauthority.com

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the legacy version of jQuery.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%baseurl%><%basename%>/site/js/jquery.js'></script>
```

Comment: That did it. I was nervous to remove it because most of the content runs off the legacy jquery. Tried $.noConflict(); but didn't seem to do anything. Thanks